# When is 意外 ever read as 頭高?

Tags: words, pronunciation, pitch-accent

I have always heard いがい{LHH}, いがいに{LHHH}, いがいと{LHHH}, but NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 seems to list いがい{HLL} too, and the same goes for [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%84%8F%E5%A4%96). I wonder if 意外 is really pronounced that way. What about the adverbs 意外と and 意外に? Are they ever 頭高?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

意外 is not pronounced いがい{HLL} in modern standard Japanese.

And in fact, NHK日本語発音アクセント**新**辞典 (2016) does not list it at all.

Only the first edition of NHK (1998) does, and its still listed second even there.

It should go without saying, but you should not use resources from 25 years ago for something as fluid as pitch accent.

Comment: If it was ever pronounced [いがい]{HLL}, I would think 意 was considered a standalone word then, like 範囲 is in 範囲外.

Comment: Sadly the newest edition doesn't seem to allow free access and the Monokakido app costs $49.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that pitch accent patterns are fluid and prone to rapid change.  I'm not sure how well known this is.

Comment: Even NHK 2016 is out of date on a portion of words (maybe a few hundred). 大辞泉 (2021) tends to do best in terms of listing the latest accent though it has its own issues (in particular with the *order* of the accents it lists, where it lists a minor accent first, making it less useful for learners).

Comment: How is it pronounced if it's not いがい?

Comment: It's my first time of hearing that Japanese pitch accent is subject to change! We have (some kind of) pitch accent in Norwegian as well, but here it's perfectly stable in and out of centuries, being a first-order phonemic property of a word. Why is the situation so different in Japanese I wonder?

Comment: @g-gundam the question is about pitch accent, not phonetics.